# How Can I Display the Map At Will?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I’ve borrowed the Whereami code found in The Big Nerd Ranch iOS book and used it in the app I’m writing. My app determines the user's location and displays it in a map in the app delegate, just like Whereami app in the book does. The `UIWindow` is made visible and displays the map correctly. From this point on, the code is my own.

My app allocates a `UINavigationController`, sets the root view controller, and proceeds to allow the user to view other view controllers and perform other methods after navigating to them.

At some point, a view controller contains a button labeled “MAP” that, when pressed, should display the map showing the user’s current location.

How can I get the app to display the `UIWindow` that is in the AppDelegate.m? I assume the app delegate is continuing to determine the user’s location, and I want the user to have the ability to display the map at will.

My current code allocates a `MapViewController` when the “MAP” button is pressed, but I can’t figure out how to get the `UIWindow` which is in the AppDelegate.m to display.

I’m thinking I should be able to do it by having a pointer to the `UIWindow` in the `MapViewController`. Is this the right approach? Do I need anything else? I'm using Xcode 4.0.2, Snow Leopard, and testing on an iOS 4 device. I'm new at this, and I don't want to get confused by upgrading to Lion, a higher Xcode, or iOS 5 yet.

Comment: The window is always being displayed. There should only be one window. The nav controller is the root view controller of the window? What is its root view controller? Where's the map view controller in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `presentModalViewController:animated:` (it's a method on all instances of `UIViewController` and its subclasses). There are a variety of transition styles you can use, like a flip or a fade.

On iOS you *very* rarely work with `UIWindow` objects. You pretty much set one up when your app launches and you leave it alone. Everything is done with `UIView` instances or the `UIViewController` instances that manage them.